# Output query to csv, codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, csv

I currently have a report that give me the users ID number and their email address, But I would like to make this in a CSV file instead of tables and rows like I currently have.

Here is my controller

```
function View_Email_E()
{
$data = array();

    if($query = $this->report_model->View_Email_English())
    {
        $data['records'] = $query;
    }
$data['main_content'] = 'view_all_email_english';
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);


}
```

Here is my model

```
    function View_Email_English()
{

    $query = $this->db->where(array('Dial_Up' => '0', 'Language' => 'English', 'Membership_Status' => 'Active'));
    $query = $this->db->like('Email', '@');
    $query = $this->db->get('Membership');
    return $query->result();
}
```

For some reason my view is not being shown in code mode, but it is an auto generated table using these this snippet of code. Each row returns ID and Email from the database.

```
<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records as $row) : ?>
```

How can I make a CSV file with just ID and email fields?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the csv_from_result function in dbutil to do it. Try something like this:

```
$csvContent = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($query);

if ( ! write_file('./path/to/file.csv', $csvContent)) {
    echo 'Unable to write the file';
} else {
    echo 'File written!';
}
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/utilities.html#csv

Comment: How could I get this to be downloaded automatically?

Comment: Where should I put the $csvContent code? in the model or controller?

Comment: I get a csv file that contains all the information on each member, not just ID# and Email, how can I limit it to those two fields?

Comment: Sorry, answered my own question, had to use a select command!

Comment: remember to load file helper, $this->load->helper('file');

Comment: in addition to file help you need to load the dbutil $this->load->dbutil();

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
$this->db->select(array('ID','Email'));
```

To your View_Email_English function.